# Maven clean install fails with connection timed out:connect error

Tags: java, maven-2, pom.xml, connection-timeout

I tried maven clean install on my project and I every time I get the following error

Maven version 2.2.1
JDK 1.7

```html
F:\Wealth>"C:\Program Files\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" cl
ean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building polo
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-cle
an-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository nunki (http://maven.apps.com/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven/org.apache.maven.plugins/poms/maven
-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository nunki-legacy (http://maven.apps.com/maven): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven2//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-cle
an-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository nunki (http://maven.apps.com/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven/org.apache.maven.plugins/poms/maven
-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository nunki-legacy (http://maven.apps.com/maven): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://maven.apps.com/maven2//org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-cl
ean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  nunki-legacy (http://maven.apps.com/maven),
  central (http://maven.apps.com/maven2/),
  nunki (http://maven.apps.com/maven2)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin
```

I have checked the proxy settings in settings.xml and I my feeling is that's the problem. But I have tried the same proxy settings to build other open source software projects and the build was success. But for this project, I see this error.

Can someone give an idea on this problem.

Comment: Start use Maven 3 and not Maven 2 anymore cause [it's EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: Okay, but I have to build this project using Maven 2.X, as its a must in the organization

Answer (score 6):

### DependencyResolutionException

*(source: [Maven Confluence](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException))*

This error generally occurs when Maven could not download dependencies. Possible causes for this error are:

1. The POM misses the declaration of the `<repository>` which hosts the artifact.
2. The repository you have configured requires authentication and Maven failed to provide the correct credentials to the server. In this case, make sure your `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` contains a `<server>` declaration whose `<id>` matches the `<id>` of the remote repository to use. See the [Maven Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) for more details.
3. The remote repository in question uses SSL and the JVM running Maven does not trust the certificate of the server.
4. There is a general network problem that prevents Maven from accessing any remote repository, e.g. a missing proxy configuration.
5. You have configured Maven to perform strict checksum validation and the files to download got corrupted.
6. Maven failed to save the files to your local repository, see [`LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException) for more details.
7. In Maven 3 if you just had a failed download and have fixed it (e.g. by uploading the jar to a repository) it will cache the failure. To force a refresh add `-U` to the command line.

In case of a general network-related problem, you could also consult the following articles:

- [Configuring a Proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)
- [Security and Deployment Settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-deployment-security-settings.html)
- [Guide to Remote Repository Access through Authenticated HTTPS](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html)

Comment: setup the correct proxy in the [${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) file solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your remote repositories all have the domain `maven.apps.com`, is that a domain in your intranet? Is Nexus running as a mirror for Maven central?

If not, you can try removing settings.xml temporarily and see if the default settings succeed.

Comment: Yes, maven.apps.com is the domain on intranet and I do not have Nexus running as mirror. Also, trying without settings.xml gives same error. Unable to download artifact from central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Comment: OK, from what I understand, your intranet does not allow outbound connections other than through a proxy. The problem here seems to be that all repositories defined in your settings.xml points to maven.apps.com on your intranet. The server at said address does not respond, all you get is a connection timeout error. What you should try next, is to edit your settings.xml file, and comment out all things regarding repositories but _leave_ the proxy configuration as is.

Comment: I will try this, how ever I am running this on our remote server, so I downloaded Source code on to my local desktop machine and tried to build from there. using the same settings.xml file my local machine is able to download all artifacts and dependencies but there was some compile error. But I have this problem on Server machine

Comment: Probable cause - if this is a production server it is most likely in setup in a DMZ where no access to Internet nor your proxy is allowed.

Comment: Its not a production server, I use this server for accessing other data sites. Connect to internet using Proxy settings. I have run maven clean install on a different open source software and it has no problem, but while trying to access this domain on intranet, I see this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, where maven couldn't download anything. After some googling and some luck, I deleted the file ~/.m2/server.xml. That fixed the problem. I haven't touched that file before, not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue and turned out that I had my settings.xml file in c:.m2\ folder. Once I moved it under user profile it work like a charm.
Perhaps it could be due to location related.