# Connection timing out while connecting to Maven repository

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to build my project in my local system using the below command

**mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true**

It fails with the below error. It is failing to connect to repo.maven.apache.org.

I pinged to the server repo.maven.apache.org, I can see the response back.

I am using maven 3 version and connecting to maven 2 repo (repo.maven.apache.org).

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building web-order-avpn 1702.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: **https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.778 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-19T21:21:10-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central
 (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.56.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Would be great if some one can suggest on what is wrong with my system?

Comment: Did not get help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725195/maven-clean-install-fails-with-connection-timed-outconnect-error

Comment: I tried all the solutions suggested in the post. But none of them works.

Comment: Does it work if you connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in a browser?  If not, then it has nothing to do with Maven.  It is simply your network issue.  If you can, then check if you need to setup proxy in Maven.

Comment: yes, I am able to access the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ in browser. I can see all the folders in that website.

Comment: Can you put your pom file here also Did you try to log in Debug with -X option?

Comment: It seems that your network connection is using a proxy. Is this the case ?

Comment: Did you get away with this issue ? I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and just like the comments suggested it was the maven proxy.  Setup in \conf\settings.xml

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html